# android - Ripple effect goes out of BottomNavigationView borders

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, ripple

I got some strange effect with my BottomNavigationView - ripple goes out of the view's borders. How can I solve it?

[image]

Here's my XML

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bnv_bottom_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_main_bottom"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/selector_bottom_navigation_item"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/selector_bottom_navigation_item" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is solved. I put the background on my BNV and now everything is fine.

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bnv_bottom_menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_main_bottom"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/selector_bottom_navigation_item"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/selector_bottom_navigation_item" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Your answer did not work for me. I put background for what is on the top of `BottomNavigationView`. In my case it was a `Fragment` (Which is added dynamically). I give background for the root layout of the `Fragment`.